# Python iteration with array

Tags: python, arrays, plot, iteration

I guess it is a simple question, I am doing simple while iteration and want to save data within data array so I can simple plot it.

```
tr = 25 #sec
fr = 50 #Hz
dt = 0.002 #2ms
df = fr*(dt/tr)
i=0;
f = 0
data = 0

while(f<50):
    i=i+1
    f = ramp(fr,f,df)
    data[i] = f

plot(data)
```

How to correctly define data array? How to save results in array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility:

```
data = []

while(f<50):
    f = ramp(fr,f,df)
    data.append(f)
```

Here, `i` is no longer needed.

Answer (score 3):

you could initialize a list like this:

```
data=[]
```

then you could add data like this:

```
data.append(f)
```

Comment: I am getting: SyntaxError: can't assign to function call

Comment: @Pepe: you can't get that error from these commands.  You would only get that message if you tried something like `data.append(i) = f`.  You probably want to use something like aix's `data.append(f)`.

Comment: @NedBatchelder obviously the OP is not familiarized with python, so that's why I used the word "array". Flagged as not constructive

Comment: @Pepe sorry as @DSM says you should use `data.append(f)`

Comment: @pacofvf: Since the word has been changed, I take back my -1!

Answer (score 0):

For plotting [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/) is a good choice and easy to install and use.

```
import pylab

pylab.plot(data)
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score -1):

He needs "i" b/c it starts from 1 in the collection. For your code to work use:

```
data = {} # this is dictionary and not list
```

Comment: The OP is asking about how to setup an array, there is no dict involved here. `data[i] = f` would be an acceptable way to index a data array if it had been initialized with something like `data=[0.0]*1000`.